# getitng "code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'" error while redirecting

Tags: node.js

here I try to run simple server using nodejs
server listen for massage to be posted to "/msg" then it write down the message to entry.txt and redirect user to "/home"

but It get error `code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'` and stop server while redirecting user witch result in display of **This site can’t be reached** page

```
import http from "http";
import fs from "fs";

export default sample_server()

function sample_server() {
    const server =  http.createServer((req ,res)=>{
        const {url , method} = req;
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
        if(url === "/home"){
            res.write("<html>")
            res.write("<head><title>page</title></head>")
            res.write("<body><center><h1>welcome</h1>")
            res.write("<form method='POST' action='/msg'>")
            res.write("<input type='text' name='msg'>")
            res.write("<input type='submit'>")
            res.write("</form></center></body></html>")
            return  res.end()
        }else if(url === "/msg" && method ==="POST"){
            res.write("<html>")
            res.write("<head><title>page</title></head>")
            res.write("<body><center><h1>massage</h1></center></body>")
            res.write("</html>")
            let msg = [];
            req.on("data"  , chunk => {
                msg.push(chunk)
            })
            req.on("end"  , () => {
                msg = Buffer.concat(msg).toString().split("=")[1]
                fs.appendFileSync("./files/entry.txt" , `entered: ${msg}\n`)
            })
            res.writeHead(302, { Location: "/home" })
            return  res.end()
        }else{
            res.write("<html>")
            res.write("<head><title>page</title></head>")
            res.write("<body><center><h1>not found</h1></center></body>")
            res.write("</html>")
            return  res.end()
        }

    })
    server.listen(3030)
}
```

I wonder if it got anything to do with  `req.on("data"  , () => {...})` or `req.on("end"  , () => {...})` running async from respons

so far I tried using

```
res.statusCode = 302;
res.setHeader("Location", "/");
```

instead of `res.writeHead(302, { Location: "/home" });` but I didn't solve the problem

Comment: why are you writing both a response body and that redirect?

Comment: Try putting the `res.writeHead(302, { Location: "/home" })` and `res.end()` inside the `end` event handler so you're not ending the request before you're done reading the incoming stream.

Comment: hello @jfriend00 . I've tried so but It didn't solve the problem with **redirecting**.the only change was that I get to see response body instead of  "This site can’t be reached"

Comment: OK, I figured out the main problem and posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to write the header AFTER you send the body, but the header needs to be sent before.  When you call the first `res.write()`, that causes the http library to send the headers (with whatever has been set up to that point).  When you then try to do `res.writeHead(302, { Location: "/home" })` later, the http engine realizes that the headers have already sent and thus you get the error `ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT` because that's literally what the http engine is discovering.  You're asking to send headers, but they've already been sent.  Obviously, you can't do things in that order.

There's also no point in sending a body to the request when you're sending a redirect (the browser won't display the body anyway so it's just a waste to send the body).

And, as I said in a comment, you should put the `res.end()` into the `end` event handler so you aren't ending the request until you're done reading the incoming stream.

And, you shouldn't be using synchronous I/O in your http server request handlers because that can ruin the ability of your server to scale.  Instead, use asynchronous file I/O.

To fix all four of these, change from this:

```
        res.write("<html>")
        res.write("<head><title>page</title></head>")
        res.write("<body><center><h1>massage</h1></center></body>")
        res.write("</html>")
        let msg = [];
        req.on("data"  , chunk => {
            msg.push(chunk)
        })
        req.on("end"  , () => {
            msg = Buffer.concat(msg).toString().split("=")[1]
            fs.appendFileSync("./files/entry.txt" , `entered: ${msg}\n`)
        })
        res.writeHead(302, { Location: "/home" })
        return  res.end()
```

to this:

```
        res.writeHead(302, { Location: "/home" })
        let msg = [];
        req.on("data"  , chunk => {
            msg.push(chunk)
        })
        req.on("end"  , () => {
            msg = Buffer.concat(msg).toString().split("=")[1]
            fs.appendFile("./files/entry.txt" , `entered: ${msg}\n`, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                res.end();
            });
        });
```